# Does the Sparkfun SAMD21 Mini/Dev Breakout work with the ATMEL Studio

Tags: atmel, atmel-studio

I'm new to the SAM product line from ATMEL. I purchased the original ATMEL Xplained board, which works nicely with the ATMEL studio for programming & debugging. I know that the Xplained board carries it's own chip for programming (I guess this is like a small ICP device).

I now want to bring the SAM D21 to my own PCB. As a starting point, I came across the dev breakout board from Sparkfun (see https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13672).

I don't see an additional chip on the sparkfun board, and I'm wondering if I can use the ATMEL Studio for programming/debugging with the ATMEL-ICE device?

Many Thanks
Christian

Comment: The only problem is does ATMEL Studio or  ATMEL-ICE device support it

Comment: oh it works quite well! Also with debugging. I ended up using the SWD interface

Comment: Good for you !!

Answer (score 1):

You need to go through the Atmel SAMD21 datasheet. I am currently using SWD pins for debugging an Atmel SAMD20 using Raspberry Pi3 which is running OpenOCD. You can use the same SWD pins to connect to an Atmel-ICE or Segger J-Link to program/debug.

You can use this as a reference: [atsamd21-arduino SWD debugging](https://learn.adafruit.com/proper-step-debugging-atsamd21-arduino-zero-m0/lets-go)